# Count until specific condition in list of dictionary provide the mean of the value

Tags: python, dictionary-comprehension

I am trying to count the number of types before the specific code, while using a `for` loop. I got a list of dictionaries and I was able to count each type, but I also need to count until the code `6501` and `6502`. Like the total number of type we have before this specific code.

```
group=[
    {'id': '123ed45','type': 'C','code':6500,'class':1,'title':'orange'},
    {'id': '123ed45','type': 'B','code':6515,'class':1,'title':'lemon'},
    {'id': '123ed45','type': 'A','code':6501,'class':1,'title':'RedApple'},
    {'id': '123ed45','type': 'C','code':6555,'class':1,'title':'banana'},
    {'id': '123ed45','type': 'B','code':6502,'class':1,'title':'Redcarrot'},
    {'id': '123ed45','type': 'A','code':6523,'class':1,'title':'pomo'}]

    [{'id': '123ed45','type': 'B','code':6555,'class':2,'title':'banana'},
    {'id': '123ed45','type': 'A','code':6501,'class':2,'title':'RedApple'},
    {'id': '123ed45','type': 'C','code':6546,'class':2,'title':'dragonfruit'},
    {'id': '123ed45','type': 'A','code':6502,'class':2,'title':'carrot'},
    {'id': '123ed45','type': 'A','code':6501,'class':2,'title':'RedApple'},
    {'id': '123ed45','type': 'B','code':6511,'class':2,'title':'pineapple'}]

    [{'id': '123ed45','type': 'A','code':6502,'class':3,'title':'Redcarrot'},
    {'id': '123ed45','type': 'C','code':6545,'class':3,'title':'lime'},
    {'id': '123ed45','type': 'B','code':6502,'class':3,'title':'carrot'},
    {'id': '123ed45','type': 'A','code':6501,'class':3,'title':'GreenApple'},
    {'id': '123ed45','type': 'C','code':6534,'class':3,'title':'grape'},
    {'id': '123ed45','type': 'A','code':6502,'class':3,'title':'carrot'}
]
```

The same set of data is available for different id's and we separated mainly on class. I got the following total count of types in each class and my concern is with only codes 6501 and 6502.

Already got this table:

[image: screenshot of table]

Further I need to calculate the number of types before code 6502 and 6501, and need the mean value of it by excluding those codes for counting and the desired output look like:

[image: screenshot of desired output]

I tried using `more-itertools`'s `spilt_at`. Is that a good try or is there any other method to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm a modest participant to `more-itertools` and like this library, but you don't need it here. It's fairly easy to keep, with `enumerate`, the current index in the current group:

```
import collections
from pprint import pprint

d = {}

for group in groups:
    for i, e in enumerate(group):
        # ('id', 'class') is the identifier of a line
        columns = d.setdefault(e['id'], {}).setdefault(e['class'], collections.Counter())
        columns[e['type']] += 1         # store the number of A, B, C
        s = "{}_{}".format(e['code'], e['title']) # build "6502_carrot" string
        if "before_"+s not in columns:  # if "before_6502_carrot" is met for the first time
            columns["before_"+s] = i    # store the current index.
        columns[s] += 1                 # store the number of "6502_carrot"

pprint(d)
```

Output:

```
{'123ed45': {1: Counter({'before_6523_pomo': 5,
                         'before_6502_Redcarrot': 4,
                         'before_6555_banana': 3,
                         'C': 2,
                         'B': 2,
                         'A': 2,
                         'before_6501_RedApple': 2,
                         '6500_orange': 1,
                         'before_6515_lemon': 1,
                         '6515_lemon': 1,
                         '6501_RedApple': 1,
                         '6555_banana': 1,
                         '6502_Redcarrot': 1,
                         '6523_pomo': 1,
                         'before_6500_orange': 0}),
             2: Counter({'before_6511_pineapple': 5,
                         'A': 3,
                         'before_6502_carrot': 3,
                         'B': 2,
                         '6501_RedApple': 2,
                         'before_6546_dragonfruit': 2,
                         '6555_banana': 1,
                         'before_6501_RedApple': 1,
                         'C': 1,
                         '6546_dragonfruit': 1,
                         '6502_carrot': 1,
                         '6511_pineapple': 1,
                         'before_6555_banana': 0}),
             3: Counter({'before_6534_grape': 4,
                         'A': 3,
                         'before_6501_GreenApple': 3,
                         'C': 2,
                         'before_6502_carrot': 2,
                         '6502_carrot': 2,
                         '6502_Redcarrot': 1,
                         'before_6545_lime': 1,
                         '6545_lime': 1,
                         'B': 1,
                         '6501_GreenApple': 1,
                         '6534_grape': 1,
                         'before_6502_Redcarrot': 0})}}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot it works, can you please explain` d.setdefault(e['id'], {}).setdefault(e['class'], collections.Counter())` this line of code and how double setdefault work here..

Comment: `d.setdefault(e['id'], {})` means `d[e'id']]` if `e['id']` is a key of `d`, else set `d[e'id']] = {}` and return the newly created dict. This expression is a dict `X`, and you can chain it with another `X.setdefault(e['class'], collections.Counter())`, that is `X[e['class']]` if `e['class']` is a key of `X`,else set `X[e['class']] = collections.Counter()` and return the newly created counter. Basically, `defaultdict` creates a new entry in the dict and returns the value.